# Eclipse android project always lauching in debug

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I feel silly asking this and even more silly to have this problem. I have a android project that has been executing fine until now.

but a couple of days ago, without me doing anything particular that I know of, my project has been always launching itself in debug no matter what I try (clicking on the debug or run gives me the same result). I try looking in the project settings and the build configuration but can't see anything justifying this.

so right now each time I launch the app I have to go to go to debug tab and click on disconnect...

Any ideas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5814936/2138983

This solution did the trick for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you checked your run configurations menu? You might have some extraneous configurations in there that Eclipse is defaulting to when you choose to launch the project.

Failing that, there is an option called "Launch in debug mode whenever the workspace contains breakpoints" in the [Run/Debug -> Launching preference page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-launching.htm). You might want to check to make sure that this option is not enabled.

As a last resort when facing these kinds of quirks I will sometimes create a new project and copy over my source files (provided the project is not very large). Closing and re-launching Eclipse sometimes works wonders for me as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but nothing fixed it ... but i know its purely this project on this computer, I imported on other computers and it works fine

Answer (score 119):

> Restart the device

I was experiencing the same problem where my app was always being run in debug mode. Restarting the device did the trick for me.

Answer (score 7):

As said above, the problem is with the device not eclipse.

Restarting the device will work, but also killing the application thread/process in the DDMS will do the same job.

Comment: I am going to try this next time.  +1 For the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

On the emulator, go to App Drawer, launch application "Dev Tools". Inside there, pick "Development Settings". Make sure that the field "Debug App" has value "(none)".

Comment: A similar solution worked for me. On my Samsung device, I went to Settings -> General -> Developer options -> Select debug app and made sure that nothing was selected.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I know I am a bit late with this one but I found a solution. It might be not acceptable for someone, but than again, it solved the problem.
I just reset my phone to factory settings. After that I was able to install the app without getting "waiting debugger to attach" message always.

Comment: Just shutting the device down and restarting it, without resetting to factory settings, did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem these days, but none of the solutions above worked for me(except for factory reset, don't wanna do that for now).

As Kennifer stated, problem is with the device since this happens only on my Zync Z5 phone (I have several other devices with Android on which app start in Run mode, not Debug mode).

The only trick that worked for me was to delete the launch configuration every time wanted to run app after a debug, but it's annoying to do this every time I need a debug.

Answer (score 2):

I'd tried *everything* on here and was surprised by the overwhelming acceptance of the top answer

> **Restart the device**

then I realised, *"this is a development phone, stop treating it like a business's server"*, and proceeded to restart.

Worth risking an answer to endorse this solution as a last resort.

My outcome- the app quickly, but quietly died. Result ! :(

Answer (score 0):

My Eclipse version:
Luna.

My case:
The option *Launch in debug mode when workspace contains breakpoints* is *Never*, but eclipse launches in debug mode.

My Solution:

- Go to Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching.
- Mark *Prompt* in option *Launch in debug mode when workspace contains breakpoints*.
- Launch.
- A dialog will popup: *There are breakpoints enabled in the workspace. Would you rather launch in debug mode?*
- Check *Remember my decision*, then press *No* button,
  and problem resolved.