# Eclipse keep deploying to device in debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, runas

After deploying to my device once for debugging, every time I try and "Run As" in regular mode it still attached the debugger.  I have deleted the application from the device and it still does this.  This causes and issue when I just want to run the app, untethered from my laptop.

Has anyone else ran into this issue?  If so, how do you fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Does clicking on the "Disconnect" button do the trick?

[image]

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. have your +1 sir.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting Eclipse.  I had this issue once and restarting Eclipse worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with this as well.  I don't recall what specifically fixed the problem, but I remember I did a combination of: 1) changing the configuration to "Run" only, 2) restarting Eclipse, and 3) trying multiple times.

One thing to keep in mind- even in "Run" mode you can see things going on in the debugger.  For instance, you still get log messages.  The main difference that I see is that it is much faster, and you don't see the threads and variables.