# Android can't get debugger to go away eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have been working with eclipse and android for a few months now and have never had this problem.  My problem is that when I don't want to run the application in debug mode, it runs it in debug mode anyways.  I added the `android:debuggable="false"` tag in my xml and now it will just hang in the "waiting for debugger" screen on the device.  Any ideas as to whats causing this?

**EDIT:**

Hmm...I restarted eclipse and the device..and it fixed everything. Feel free to close this question

Comment: You can delete your own question, if you so choose.

Comment: visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342588/eclipse-android-project-always-lauching-in-debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting the emulator and Eclipse - this always clears up that problem for me.