# Eclipse runs debug mode even when I click "run"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eclipse always starts my app on debug mode even though i click the regular "run" button...

Any ideas?

Comment: It'd be useful to know versions of Eclipse, the Google plugin, your device, and the OS you're using.

Comment: Just happened to me too. Eclipse Indigo SR1 20110916-0149, ADT 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398, Xperia X8 Android 2.3.7 (GingerDX v020), Windows 7 x64 SP1. Device reboot helped. It seems that this problem occured when I accidently double- or triple-clicked debug icon in Eclipse... I couldn't reproduce it tho.

Comment: Restarting the Android device is the only thing that works.

Comment: having this issue also.  None of the solutions listed here worked.  Running Juno...

Comment: This answer helped me [Eclipse android project always lauching in debug][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342588/eclipse-android-project-always-lauching-in-debug

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found that I had to reboot my Xoom to get it to work properly again.

Answer (score 4):

When this happened to me I found that I had left a call to android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger() in the code, which was causing the debugger to attach. Removing those calls fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

try to select Run -> Remove All Breakpoints, and run your project again

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is saying that is not clicking the Run Debug button. So how Remove All Breakpoints should affect it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the perspective DDMS , and run your app, and then , you will see the icon of debugging in the process of your app , uncheck it and it will work ;

if id didn't work , open the perspective Debug  ,then, disable all the breakpoints ,  and it will work

Comment: if it doesnt work , try the second solution : disable all breakpoints in the Debug Perspective

Comment: they are already disabled.
BTW i discovered that it only happens to me with this project.
and it happens even if i set 'debuggable' to false or if i even export and sign the application! It always attempts to connect to the debugger.

Comment: Sorry @Houcine, doesn't work for me either.  I'm seeing the same problem.  Rebooting the Galaxy Tab I'm using solved the problem for me, but it looks like it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Eclipse and the emulator.  That always works for me.

Comment: Does destroying the emulator and creating a new one still show the problem?  (FYI, it's not limited to the emulator; I'm seeing the same thing on a Galaxy Tab 10.1, Android 3.1)