# ADT Eclipse/Android always builds/runs in debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

To all,

Busy writing my first Android app, using ADT/Eclipse. I use my phone as deployment environment, since the emulator is too slow on my PC.

Making great progress, except that lately the application is always deployed in debug mode, even if I 'run' the application in normal mode.

Tried rebuilding/uninstalling, but whatever I do, it has no impact.

Any help appreciated.
Barry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Restarting the device should solve your problem.

You can find details here: [eclipse-android-project-always-lauching-in-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342588/eclipse-android-project-always-lauching-in-debug)

---

Also take a look at [eclipse-runs-debug-mode-even-when-i-click-run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460370/eclipse-runs-debug-mode-even-when-i-click-run)